# How to append a tag after a link with BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

Starting from an Html input like this:

```
<p>
<a href="http://www.foo.com">this if foo</a>
<a href="http://www.bar.com">this if bar</a>
</p>
```

using BeautifulSoup, i would like to change this Html in:

```
<p>
<a href="http://www.foo.com">this if foo</a><b>OK</b>
<a href="http://www.bar.com">this if bar</a><b>OK</b>
</p>
```

Is it possible to do this using BeautifulSoup?

Something like:

```
from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup
soup = BeautifulSoup(html)
for link_tag in soup.findAll('a'):
    link_tag = link_tag + '<b>OK</b>' #This obviously does not work
```

Comment: Yes, it is possible. BeautifulSoup has pretty good documentation:

http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/documentation.html

Post your code if you have problems and I (and others) will help.

Comment: Actually this particular manipulation is not trivial to pick up from the documentation.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have the right idea. Just match up the types, and do `replaceWith`.

```
from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup
soup = BeautifulSoup(html)
for link_tag in soup.findAll('a'):
    link_tag.replaceWith( link_tag.prettify() + '<b>OK</b>' )
print soup
```

should give you:

```
<p>
 <a href="http://www.foo.com">
this if foo
</a>
<b>OK</b>
 <a href="http://www.bar.com">
this if bar
</a>
<b>OK</b>
</p>
```

Comment: Note for anyone hitting this answer from Google etc, in BS4 there is a insert_after() method, for example: `b = soup.new_tag("b"); b.string = "OK"; link_tag.insert_after(b)` ought to work.

Answer (score 8):

You can use BeautifulSoup's [insert](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/documentation.html#Adding%20a%20Brand%20New%20Element) to add the element in the right place:

```
from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup
soup = BeautifulSoup(html)

for link_tag in soup.findAll('a'):
    link_tag_idx = link_tag.parent.contents.index(link_tag)
    link_tag.parent.insert(link_tag_idx + 1, '<b>OK</b>')
```

This works for the example you give, though I'm not sure it's the only or most efficient method.

Comment: I think the last line should be ` link_tag.parent.insert(link_tag_idx + 1, BeautifulSoup("<br>"))` as the "<" and ">" do not get converted properly on my machine.

Comment: `soup.insert(i, tag)` is pretty counter-intuitive, as `i` doesn't directly mean anything.(Because my `soup.body.contents` = `['\n', '<div>...</div>', '\n',  '<script>...</script>', '\n', ...]`.) `.append()`, `.insert_after()` works OK, though. PS: @sup you should use `br = soup.new_tag('br')`.