# Inserting into a html file using python

Tags: python, html, html-parsing

I have a html file where I would like to insert a `<meta>` tag between the `<head>` & `</head>` tags using python. If I open the file in `append` mode how do I get to the relevant position where the `<meta>` tag is to be inserted?

Comment: What you describe isn't appending, it is inserting (as you yourself state).  Append mode allows you to add to the end of the file, and thus won't help here.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Use [BeautifulSoup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/). Here's an example where a `meta` tag is inserted right after the `title` tag using [insert_after()](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#insert-before-and-insert-after):

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as Soup

html = """
<html>
<head>
<title>Test Page</title>
</head>
<body>
<div>test</div>
</html>
"""
soup = Soup(html)

title = soup.find('title')
meta = soup.new_tag('meta')
meta['content'] = "text/html; charset=UTF-8"
meta['http-equiv'] = "Content-Type"
title.insert_after(meta)

print soup
```

prints:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Test Page</title>
        <meta content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" http-equiv="Content-Type"/>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div>test</div>
    </body>
</html>
```

You can also find `head` tag and use [insert()](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#insert) with a specified position:

```
head = soup.find('head')
head.insert(1, meta)
```

Also see:

- [Add parent tags with beautiful soup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10182685/add-parent-tags-with-beautiful-soup)
- [How to append a tag after a link with BeautifulSoup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2908362/how-to-append-a-tag-after-a-link-with-beautifulsoup)

Comment: One way to do it:  


    with open("/file/name.html", "r")
        soup = Soup(file)
    title = soup.find('title')
    meta = soup.new_tag('meta')
    meta['content'] = "text/html; charset=UTF-8"
    meta['http-equiv'] = "Content-Type"
    title.insert_after(meta)
    with open("/file/name.html", "w") as f:
        f.write(str(soup)) 


It worked for me, thanks.