# Inserting a html file into python file

Tags: python, windows, flask

I'm using Pycharm on Windows 10 and I'd like to use a html file inside a python file, so what should I do? I have my code already written, but the webpage seems not to run this html file.

To visualize this, I share my code:

```
from flask import Flask, render_template

app=Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def home():
    return render_template("home.html")


@app.route('/about/')
def about():
    return render_template("about.html")

if __name__=="__main__":
    app.run(debug=True)
```

And after deploying this python file locally, I'd like these htmls to work, but the program doesn't seem to see them. Where should I put these html files or what should I do with them? I have them all in a one folder on my PC.

Comment: What do you mean by "use an html file inside a python file"? What do you mean by "run this html file"? An html file is text, so it's not clear how you would "run" a text document. What is "the webpage"? Are you running a web server?

Comment: You can serve html files locally on `http://localhost:8000` by using `python -m http.server 8000` in the directory containing your html files. https://docs.python.org/3/library/http.server.html#module-http.server

Comment: @HåkenLid I'm new here so I still don't know the terminology, but as you can see in the code above, I'd like to use html file inside a python file, but I don't know how to connect them. I was reading about templates (as you can see render_templates), but I still have no idea how to merge them inside Pycharm.

Comment: Do you get a `TemplateNotFound` exception, or any exception at all? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23327293/flask-raises-templatenotfound-error-even-though-template-file-exists?noredirect=1&lq=1

Answer (score 1):

Use [`BeautifulSoup`](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/). Here's an example there a meta tag is inserted right after the title tag using [`insert_after()`](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#insert-before-and-insert-after):

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as Soup

html = """
<html>
<head>
<title>Test Page</title>
</head>
<body>
<div>test</div>
</html>
"""
soup = Soup(html)

title = soup.find('title')
meta = soup.new_tag('meta')
meta['content'] = "text/html; charset=UTF-8"
meta['http-equiv'] = "Content-Type"
title.insert_after(meta)

print soup
```

prints:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Test Page</title>
        <meta content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" http-equiv="Content-Type"/>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div>test</div>
    </body>
</html>
```

You can also find head tag and use insert() with a specified position:

```
head = soup.find('head')
head.insert(1, meta)
```

---

Also see:

- [Add parent tags with beautiful soup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10182685/add-parent-tags-with-beautiful-soup)
- [How to append a tag after a link with BeautifulSoup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2908362/how-to-append-a-tag-after-a-link-with-beautifulsoup)